# Adding a lot images on a box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am just creating a table and I have 2 images on this table.I have 1 image in one box ,color black and 1 image on a box that it is red.I take the images with css. I want to have in  the one box  that I have the black ,another 14 images,so in one box I will have 15 images.If you see (1,1) there located the black image.In that position I want another 14 images of blacks.I didn't know how to do that .This code is for to create my table and those pictures inside.

```
 let colors={black:"https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg",red:'https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png'}
  //
  
  let items = [
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "piece":"p",
    "piece_color": "black",
    "b_color": "black"
  },
  {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 2,
    "piece":"p",
    "piece_color": "red",
    "b_color": "red"
  }
  ];
  $(function () {
    draw_empty_board();
    fill_board();
    //$('#do_move').click(do_move);
    //$('#chess_reset').click(do_reset);
});

  function draw_empty_board() {
    var t='<table id="chess_table">';
    for(var i=2;i>0;i--) {
        
        t += '<tr>';
        t += '<td class="line_label">'+i+'</td>';
        for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
            
        
            t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_'+j+'_'+i+'"></td>'; 
            
        }
        t+='</tr>';
    }
    t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
    for(var j=1;j<13;j++) {
        
        t += '<td class="column_label">'+j+'</td>';
    }
    t+='</tr>';
    t+='</table>';
    
    $('#chess_board').html(t);
}
function fill_board() {
    //$.ajax({url: "chess.php/board/", success: fill_board_by_data });
    //I'm a calling static data here
    fill_board_by_data(items);
    
}

function fill_board_by_data(data) {
    
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

        var o = data[i];
        var id = '#square_'+ o.x +'_' + o.y;
        //var c = (o.piece!=null)?o.piece_color + o.piece:'';
        var c = (o.piece!=null)?o.piece_color:'';
        
        //$(id).append('<span class="'+c+'dot"></span>');
        var im = (o.piece!=null)?'<img class="piece" src="'+colors[c]+'.png">':'';
        $(id).addClass(o.b_color+'_square').html(im);
        
    }
}
```

the css code is this

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:2px solid;
  }
  td{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid;
  }
  
  /*this is a suggested Css alternative to images */
.reddot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
    .blackdot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
img{width:25px;}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chess_board"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show excepted output ?

Comment: @Swati https://ibb.co/m07B35t thats how. The red are 15 in a box (12,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `o.piece_color` is red or black depending on this assign total `images` you need to add inside `td` .Then , just use `for-loop` this will run until count inside this loop append `images` to some variable using `+=` and finally append this to your required td.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let colors = {
  black: "https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg",
  red: 'https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png'
}
//

let items = [{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "piece": "p",
    "piece_color": "black",
    "b_color": "black"
  },
  {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 2,
    "piece": "p",
    "piece_color": "red",
    "b_color": "red"
  }
];
$(function() {
  draw_empty_board();
  fill_board();
});

function draw_empty_board() {
  var t = '<table id="chess_table">';
  for (var i = 2; i > 0; i--) {

    t += '<tr>';
    t += '<td class="line_label">' + i + '</td>';
    for (var j = 1; j < 13; j++) {


      t += '<td class="chess_square" id="square_' + j + '_' + i + '"></td>';

    }
    t += '</tr>';
  }
  t += '<tr><td class="column_label line_label"></td>';
  for (var j = 1; j < 13; j++) {

    t += '<td class="column_label">' + j + '</td>';
  }
  t += '</tr>';
  t += '</table>';

  $('#chess_board').html(t);
}

function fill_board() {
  fill_board_by_data(items);
}

function fill_board_by_data(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var o = data[i];
    var id = '#square_' + o.x + '_' + o.y;
    var c = (o.piece != null) ? o.piece_color : '';
    var im = (o.piece != null) ? '<img class="piece" src="' + colors[c] + '.png">' : '';
    var htmls = ''; //delcare this
    //check color if black 14 or 15(red)
    var count = (o.piece_color == "black") && (o.piece != null) ? 14 : 15
    //loop till count
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      //append img
      htmls += '<img class="piece" src="' + colors[c] + '.png">';
    }
    //finally add img inside td
    $(id).addClass(o.b_color + '_square').html(htmls)


  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid;
}

td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
}


/*this is a suggested Css alternative to images */

.reddot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blackdot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chess_board"></div>
```